# php cast JSON array keys to integer

Tags: php, json

I need array keys in json array to be integers. Now they are strings. Could you tell me where is my mistake?

```
   $i = 0;
   while($i < 7) {
       isset($ips[date('d', $week_start + $i * 86400)])
           ? $ips[(int)date('d', $week_start + $i * 86400)] = count(date('d', $week_start + $i * 86400))
           : $ips[(int)date('d', $week_start + $i * 86400)] = 0;

       isset($time[date('d', $week_start + $i * 86400)])
           ? $time[(int)date('d', $week_start + $i * 86400)] = count(date('d', $week_start + $i * 86400))
           : $time[(int)date('d', $week_start + $i * 86400)] = 0;

       $i++;
   }

   return json_encode(array('unique' => $time, 'impressions' => $ips));
```

Comment: If your keys are strings how can they be converted to integers?

Comment: well thats the problem. Is there anyway to make cast them to int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible with `json_encode` or `json` format

Look at this 2 arrays

```
$array = array("A","B","C","D");
$array2 = array(2=>"A",7=>"B",11=>"C",70=>"D");
```

Run

```
 var_dump($array,$array2);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'A' (length=1)
  1 => string 'B' (length=1)
  2 => string 'C' (length=1)
  3 => string 'D' (length=1)
array
  2 => string 'A' (length=1)
  7 => string 'B' (length=1)
  11 => string 'C' (length=1)
  70 => string 'D' (length=1)
```

You can see in `PHP` the are both `Array`

Now run

```
 var_dump(json_encode($array),json_encode($array2));
```

Output

```
string '["A","B","C","D"]' (length=17)
string '{"2":"A","7":"B","11":"C","70":"D"}' (length=35)
```

**Conclusion**

If you are setting array keys and those keys does not start with `0` and increase serially  it would be encoded as `json` object

If you want just arrays

```
 var_dump(json_encode(array_values($array2)));
```

Output

```
 string '["A","B","C","D"]' (length=17)
```

Answer (score 2):

The key in an object [must be a string](http://json.org/). If you want to not have strings then you must use sequential integer keys starting from 0, which will result in an array instead.

Comment: wasted bandwidth all those commas